# Selectpicker title change text

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/. I am using multi-select dropdown. On selecting some items, it shows its default title "x items selected". I want to change its text to "x some_other_word selected.". Anyone tell me, if this plugin provides any option to change the title text.

Answer (score 5):

you can use "data-count-selected-text"

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>3"
    data-count-selected-text= "{0} some_other_word selected">
     <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
      <option>Onions</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "count format" use

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>3">
 <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
  <option>Onions</option> </select>
```

or you can directly edit the plugin and add extended option to define your default "selected" text format.

Comment: "<select id="dropdown" class="selectpicker form-control" name="ids[]" data-live-search= "true" title="Select Service" data-selected-text-format="count>3" multiple>" I am using this.
Is it advisable to edit the plugin. Can you tell how to add extended option.

Answer (score 0):

Add title value to "x some_other_word selected".

```
 <select class="selectpicker" title="x some_other_word selected.">
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: x is number of items selected not some random variable.